# CI/CD for Flutter Apps Using GitHub Actions

Tags: flutter, github, apk, github-actions

I'm trying out GitHub Actions to build my Flutter app but I got this error every time.
when executing `flutter build apk` command got this error.

Code of main.yml file.

```
name: main

# This workflow is triggered on pushes to the repository.

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    
# on: push    # Default will running for every branch.
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'

    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        channel: 'stable' 
        flutter-version: '3.0.0' 

    - run: flutter pub get
    
    - run: flutter format --set-exit-if-changed .
    
    - run: flutter build apk

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: release-apk
        path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the logs. Also, note that you can re-run a step in debug mode. Lastly, please remember to avoid images for logs and errors, because only text allows future people to search by error messages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create the directory .github/workflows:

[image]

```
name: main

# This workflow is triggered on pushes to the repository.

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    
# on: push    # Default will running for every branch.
    
jobs:
  build:
    # This job will run on windows virtual machine
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    
    # Setup Java environment in order to build the Android app.
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    
    # Setup the flutter environment.
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        channel: 'stable' # 'dev', 'alpha', default to: 'stable'
        flutter-version: '3.3.4' # you can also specify exact version of flutter
    
    # Get flutter dependencies.
    - run: flutter clean
    - run: flutter pub get
    
    # Build apk.
    - run: flutter build apk --release
    
    # Upload generated apk to the artifacts.
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: release-apk
        path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```